# What is Compatible "int" type in both 32Bit & 64Bit windows in C++?

Tags: c++, types, 32bit-64bit

What is the compatible "int" datatype in C++ that can resize itself to 4 bytes on 32bit & 8 bytes on 64bit windows?

Although INT_PTR works fine but it reduces the readability as well as its description tells us to use it for pointer arithmetic.

Thanks

Comment: I thought the problem is the other way round - that you need a datatype that does not resize. With resizing datatypes you have the problem that the code may run on one system and not on the other.

Comment: *int* is usually the fastest integral type of the platform. If you need this to count in a loop for example, just use *int* and let the compiler do the dirty tricks for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something standard, you're out of luck. The standard does not specify the size of any of the built-in datatypes.

Note, that `INT_PTR` does not imply pointer arithmetic. I means that the type will have the same size as `void *`, which is exactly what you want. It won't work on all platforms though (I'm pretty sure it's Windows specific).

Answer (score 3):

The standard does not mention specific size requirements, only that each integral type must provide at least as much storage as the type before it. So `int` must hold as much as a `short`, and so on. You're better off specifying what you need them for.

If you're looking for integers that do not change size based on the operating environment, take a look at the [Boost Integer Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/integer/index.html), or the C99/C++11 header `<cstdint>`. This contains types such as `uint32_t`/`int32_t` and `uintmax_t`/`intmax_t`.

Most importantly, based off your question, it has: `uintptr_t`/`intptr_t`. These are guaranteed to have the correct size to hold a pointer on your platform.

Comment: `signed size_t`? Perhaps you meant gcc's `ssize_t`? :)

Comment: @avakar: (Almost three years later...) Fixed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

under Visual Studio you are also offered __int3264 which does much the same as INT_PTR ...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the compiler. I think the only (more or less) reliable way is by using a pointer type like (void *).

I think the best way is by using some conditional processing in your header file and set a custom type:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
  typedef __int64 NATIVEINT;
#else
  typedef __int32 NATIVEINT;
#endif
```

(this sample is for Visual C++)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2006/04/msg00681.html. Unfortunatly your question seems to be compiler dependant.